# Override polyglossia language feature

Tags: polyglossia

I'm using the package [`polyglossia`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), setting the language to `nynorsk`. I notice, however, that `polyglossia`'s feature for the `abstract` environment is incorrect, since `Sammendrag` is not Nynorsk. How can I override this and provide my own heading in this case?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And the `babel` answer works for `polyglossia` too, so I don't think a bounty is really needed: `\addto\captionsnynorsk{\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstrakt}}` (or whatever word you want.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I'll edit the accepted answer yonder and close this question (EDIT: you beat me to it! ``:)``).